# Load html table from URL

Tags: jquery

In my HTML there is one div tag

```
  <div id="aaa"></div>
```

and for example my URL is `www.xyz.com`. now I want to load the contents of table from that url in my div tag.
I have tried this

```
$('#aaa').load('www.xyz.com', function () {

});
```

but not success. How can i do this?. Thanks.

Comment: no success.. does not tell us anything... please mention if you have an error... or paste your error here..you can check it in your developer tool console tab

Comment: @bipen It does not give any error.

Comment: `$('#aaa').load('www.xyz.com #TableID', function () {});` will load a spesific content..

Answer (score 1):

First of all: make sure you're loading in jQuery before calling your code. Obvious, I know, but there are a surprising number of posts on SO from people who don't check this first.

Is the page that you're trying to load on the same website? If so, pass in the ID of the table:

```
$('#aaa').load('path/to/test.html #tableId');
```

If it's not on the same domain, you're going to have problems with [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

According to the [jQuery `load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide a fully qualified URL, the URL you pass to `load` is resolved relative to the current URL.  Therefore, if your page is at `http://www.example.com/somefolder/`, loading `www.xyz.com` will attempt to retrieve a resource from `http://www.example.com/somefolder/www.xyz.com`.

Try this instead:

```
$('#aaa').load('http://www.xyz.com', function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iFrame?

```
<div id="aaa">
    <iframe src="http://www.xyz.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Can you be a bit more specific? Do you want to load a certain part in only?